# Disk Management Hidden Partitions - PTEDIT32

Tags: partitioning, partition-recovery

Apparently PTEDIT32 can edit partitions, making partitions that are hidden, visible. My purpose is to take a hidden partition on a toshiba laptop (the recovery partition) and copy it as my hard drive is beginning to fail.

My problem, is that I cannot find PTEDIT32 documentation on what I want to change the partition # to. I know that changing it from 27 to 7 would change it from hidden to active - but if I set it to active, I am worried it will try to launch the recovery mode (as that is what it did on a previous laptop)

Here is the link I used for instructions to do this on a previous laptop:  [Hidden_Recovery_Link_Site](http://www.pctechbytes.net/showthread.php/15418-How-to-use-Acer-Aspire-hidden-partition)
So how to make the hidden partition visible without it actually RUNNING the recovery mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Acronis Disk Director will do a direct "clone" of the hard drive including boot partitions and the hidden partitions.

I have not used it for the notebook, but have used it for a desktop with success.  This should solve the issue.

In addition it will allow marking of a partition as "Active" so that you can access the files on the hidden partition.